# $parse in Angular (2/4)

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have an AngularJS component that takes in a string template which I compile like so, and later use to render various items:

```
this.$parse(template);
```

I'd like to do something in an Angular component (v.4.0.0-rc.3), but I'm having a hard time finding a solution.  I've found a few examples; however, they're all from the Angular 2 beta and don't appear to work ([Example here](https://github.com/PawelGerr/angular2-interpolatio)).

So far I have the compiler services added to my module:

```
import { COMPILER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/compiler';
...
providers: [
        COMPILER_PROVIDERS,
   ]
```

and I'm pulling in and calling the parser service:

```
constructor(private parser: Parser) { }
...

var ast = this.parser.parseInterpolation(template, null);
```

I'm a little lost past this point.  Digging into the weeds this was the only reference to that type I could find in [Angular's source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bebedfed24d6fbfa492e97f071e1d1b41e411280/packages/compiler/src/view_compiler/view_compiler.ts#L239).

Am I on the right track here?  I feel like there should be a simple solution to interpolating given a template and context to a string

Answer (score 0):

My reasoning for this was I wanted to take the standard 'How to set the window title based on the route' example and make it more dynamic.

From this:

```
{
        path: 'users',
        component: UserComponent,
        resolve: { user: UserResolver },
        data: {title: 'User'}
}
```

to this:

```
{
        path: 'users',
        component: UserComponent,
        resolve: { user: UserResolver },
        data: {title: 'User {{user.name}}'}
}
```

Since I have full control over what's happening, interpolation is probably overkill, and I just updated my parsing logic to understand the title property could be a string or function, and what to do if it is a function:

```
if (snapshot.data['title']) {
    let title = snapshot.data['title'] as (string | Function);
    if (typeof title === 'function') {
        titleParts.push(title(snapshot.data));
    } else {
        titleParts.push(title);
    }
}
```

Where the route becomes:

```
{
    path: 'users',
    component: UserComponent,
    resolve: { user: UserResolver },
    data: {title: (ctx: any) => `User ${(ctx.user as User).Name}`}
}
```

This isn't the solution for every situation, but I figured it might help if anyone else is trying to do something similar.

Comment: Can you show any implementation details for your solution? This does not appear to be an answer, but rather additional details belonging in the question itself.